# MPX File Is Not Being Imported In Primavera p6 Software

Tags: java, import, mpxj, primavera

I convert primavera xer file in to mpx formate using `MPXWriter` class. File converted successfully into mpx format. But when i will try to import file in primavera p6 software its give error

```
Import/Export Error: Cannot find a unique value for wbs_short_name in PROJWBS. Last value is 109989 L3 - LIVE X.12.1.109989 - Const.1008
```

I am getting this above error. attached screen short as per below. please help me for solved this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have an XER file you shouldn't convert it to MPX. Either import it as is or, if its version is higher than P6 version, open the XER file in notepad and modify the version.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you use MP XML import/export - especially with P6R16.x onwards.  MPP/MPX has rarely been successful in any version of P6 that purported to support it.
(ps. I know this is an old question, but posting in case anyone else has the same question).